# Deformation quantization of infinite dimensional Poisson manifolds

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, deformation-theory, poisson-geometry, quantization

In 1999, Karaali wrote [a review of formal deformation quantization](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ealanw/242papers99/karaali.pdf) for a class she took with Weinstein.
She ends the paper with the following remark:

> Another question that remains involves the infinite dimensional case: ***Kontsevich‘s results settle the problem in the finite dimensional case, but there are places in physics where we have to deal with
> infinite dimensional Poisson manifolds***, i.e infinite dimensional manifolds with a Poisson structure on them. This case involves new problems and perhaps may shed light on a better mathematical understanding of quantum field theory.

Since then, it seems that techniques constructed by Schlichenmaier settled this problem for infinite-dimensional symplectic manifolds, as claimed in [nLab](http://%5BnLab%20claims%5D%5B2%5D).

More recently, in [a paper by Hawkins and Rejzner](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09157), a deformation quantization for infinite-dimensional *affine* manifolds has been constructed.
They also review the problem stated above, and mention that it is still open.

- What is the current status of formal deformation quantization of infinite-dimensional Poisson manifolds?